# How do I change the font style, font size and placement of app name in the actionbar of my app in android studio?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, fonts

I want to change the font style, font size and positioning of the app name in my action bar to more to the centre, in android studio. I can't find anything when looking up how to do this on the internet. Does anyone know how this is done? My app name is located in my String.xml file. This is currently the only line of code in this file:

```
    <resources>
    <string name="app_name">TestApp</string>
</resources>
```

In which file in my app do I add the code to change these characteristics regarding the app name in the actionbar at the top of the page and what is that code I need?

Answer (score 1):

Go to the `styles.xml` and add this code:

```
<resources>
<style name="CustomActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:layout_gravity">center</item>
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/CustomActionBarTitleText</item>
</style>

<style name="CustomActionBarTitleText" parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:typeface">monospace</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

and then when you do that go to the `AndroidManifest.xml` and add this code:

```
android:theme="@style/CustomActionBar"
```

Finally in your java file add this:

```
getSupportActionBar().setTitle(R.string.app_name);
```

I hope this helps you and answer your question. Please let me know if you have any problem.

> By the way if styles.xml does not exist by default you have to create
> it.

Comment: This didn't work, I added all the code as shown but my app stopped working so I had to just change everything back to how it was before.

Answer (score 0):

The more efficient way would be to remove the default status bar from your theme and create a custom toolbar. This way, you will create a toolbar according to your design.

In themes.xml

change this-

```
<style name="Theme.MatricApp" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
```

to this-

```
<style name="Theme.MatricApp" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
```

Then in your XML layout design your own toolbar.

Comment: How do I design my own toolbar though?

Comment: @Marfog509 Follow this link to design custom toolbar-   https://qureshi-ayaz29.medium.com/custom-toolbar-in-android-3818a0740942